# Help using ST_Buffer for points

Tags: postgis, postgresql, buffer

So I am trying to do a where clause on a select and my code is

```
ST_Within(shape::GEOMETRY, ST_Buffer(ST_GeogFromText('@Value(_location)'), 5, 'endcap=round join=round')
```

I am trying to buffer the _location attribute by 5 meters so when the ST_Within is used it will help match better.  This code is suppose to look for for input points and see if they match anything in the data set already. via spatial match.  Just FYI both points for ST_within are points.

If anyone has any idea how i used ST_Bufffer wrong that would be great help.

Comment: Please **edit** the question to specify the exact PostgreSQL release, the PostGIS release, and the SRID associated with the table.  It's likely you're finding all features within 5 Cartesian degrees (~550+km).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find it diffucult to see what question you are asking here, but for sure you are using the buffer in a wrong manner. It should be a 
`ST_Dwithin(shape, ST_GeogFromText('@Value(_location)'),5)`

You can read more over here: http://postgis.net/2013/08/26/tip_ST_DWithin/